# docs.rs doesn't build when I publish a crate that includes features in ndarray-linalg

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates, nalgebra

I think [How to build documentation of an FFI crate without the native library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158261/how-to-build-the-docs-rs-documentation-of-an-ffi-crate-when-the-native-library-i) is a related question, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation. I'm using the [`ndarray-linalg`](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray-linalg) crate which extends the features of `ndarray`, but it requires users to specify [backend features](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray-linalg#backend-features). I tried uploading my crate, which is a library, to crates.io with the `openblas-static` feature enabled, and while the library builds fine, docs.rs gives me a build error:

```
[INFO] [stderr] error: failed to run custom build command for `openblas-src v0.10.8`
[INFO] [stderr] 
[INFO] [stderr] Caused by:
[INFO] [stderr]   process didn't exit successfully: `/opt/rustwide/target/debug/build/openblas-src-3b8b898cc07c115f/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
[INFO] [stderr]   --- stderr
[INFO] [stderr]   thread 'main' panicked at /opt/rustwide/cargo-home/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openblas-src-0.10.8/build.rs:176:52:
[INFO] [stderr]   called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases/download/v0.3.21/OpenBLAS-0.3.21.tar.gz: Dns Failed: resolve dns name 'github.com:443': failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution
[INFO] [stderr] 
[INFO] [stderr]   Caused by:
[INFO] [stderr]       failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution
[INFO] [stderr]   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
[INFO] [stderr] warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I've since updated my Cargo.toml to alias the features:

```
...
[dependencies]
...
ndarray = "0.15.6"
ndarray-linalg = "0.16.0"

[features]
openblas-static = ["ndarray-linalg/openblas-static"]
openblas-system = ["ndarray-linalg/openblas-system"]
netlib-static = ["ndarray-linalg/netlib-static"]
netlib-system = ["ndarray-linalg/netlib-system"]
intel-mkl-static = ["ndarray-linalg/intel-mkl-static"]
intel-mkl-system = ["ndarray-linalg/intel-mkl-system"]
```

This builds fine now if I run something like `cargo build -F openblas-static` and the docs build fine if I run `cargo docs -F openblas-static`, but I'm really wondering what will happen when I upload it. Side note, is it not a bit silly that crates.io and docs.rs require a version bump every time you upload, even for aesthetic changes? Anyway, is this the preferred method of doing what I want, and should I upload it with `cargo upload -F openblas-static` or is there a cleaner way of getting around this? Or is this error entirely unrelated to the inclusion of this feature?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what the actual question is. If you want to enable the `openblas-static` feature in your crate while docs.rs builds it, you can add `[package.metadata.docs.rs] features = [ "openblas-static" ]` to your `Cargo.toml`. Does that address the question?

Comment: @user2722968 I think that might be on the right path, but I believe the issue on docs.rs comes from building with `openblas-static` in the first place. The first (failed) upload just included it as a feature of `ndarray-linalg`, so if anything I would rather have a way to either skip the docs for the `ndarray-linalg` library, or better yet, figure out why `openblas-static` failed in the first place. Important note: it *does not* fail when I build docs on my own computer.

Comment: You can look at how other [reverse dependencies of `ndarray-linalg`](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray-linalg/reverse_dependencies) build their documentation.

Comment: @user2722968 this answer was so obvious I feel silly for not thinking of it in the first place, thanks! Looking at the [Cargo.toml of ndarray-glm](https://github.com/felix-clark/ndarray-glm/blob/master/Cargo.toml), they seem to implement the same thing that I was thinking of, so I'm going to try to upload it and see what happens. Version 0.1.1, here we come :/