# How to access current cargo profile (debug/release, …) from the build script (build.rs)

Tags: build, rust, embedded

In an embedded project, I usually run the debug mode with qemu, but need to build the release for a concrete microcontroller.

The build.rs would need to know what the actual mode is (debug or release) to generate the correct memory layout.

How can the build.rs make this decision?

Related: [How to access current cargo profile (build, test, bench, doc, ....) from the build script (build.rs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446642/how-to-access-current-cargo-profile-build-test-bench-doc-from-the-bui)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's written in the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts):

> `PROFILE` - `"release"` for release builds, `"debug"` for other builds.

This goes into build.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    let profile = std::env::var("PROFILE").unwrap();
    match profile.as_str() {
        "debug" => (),
        "release" => (),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Comment: To be more compliant with Rust good practices, and also to avoid panics, your example should match against `std::env::var("PROFILE")` directly, so it can take actions when an Err is returned.

Comment: The decision needs to be made at compile time, as stated, this is an embedded project, without access to std.

Comment: @ÁkosVandra the code here is mean to be place un build.rs and so is used only at compile time

Comment: Is there a way to get the specific profile name, not just debug or release?