# Is it possible to invoke a build.rs only for release mode?

Tags: rust, release, rust-cargo

In a Rust crate, is it possible to invoke a build.rs only for release mode?

One can specify it in Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
build = "build.rs"
```

The issue is, for development, it delays the beginning of compiling the crate's sources. The [Cargo guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) doesn't seem to offer such an option.

Comment: Interesting, even `#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]` (or similar) in `build.rs` isn't working.
Something like:
`[profile.release]
build = "build.rs"`
isn't working either

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to access current cargo profile (debug/release, …) from the build script (build.rs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57296104/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be able to make runs of `build.rs` less frequent by emitting `rerun-if-changed=PATH` lines.

Comment: My question seeks to minimize the time taken to get compiler messages during development, \\

Comment: Thanks, Shepmaster.  Here's what is different about this question.

Comment: The question is how to reduce edit-compile-error-messages delay.    rerun_if_changed_path("path/file") has a far smaller delay than "if profile.as_str() == "release"."  Thanks very much to Sven Marnach. There is additional example code for rerun_if_changed_path here: https://crates.io/crates/build-deps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this build script. `Cargo` passes `PROFILE` environment variable to `rustc` invokation, which can be used to determinate active profile.

```
// build.rs
use std::env;

pub fn main() {
    if Ok("release".to_owned()) == env::var("PROFILE") {
        panic!("I'm only panicking in release mode")
    }
}
```